# C# - get BaseType.Name and Namespace of the Page from base class

Tags: c#, class, radix

I've a base class for my all pages:

```
//BASE CLASS
public class WebBasePage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
          base.OnLoad(e);
          string pageBaseTypeName = ????
          string pageBaseTypeNameMespace = ????
    }
}
//PAGE
public partial class T350112A : WebBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some code.
    }
}
```

I want the OnLoad event of this base class to dynamically get the BaseType.Name and the Namespace of the Page that called the base class.

Is It possible?

Comment: do you need a 'name' or you need to differentiate (e.g. do something) based on the type of the class - there are many ways, depends on what you need it for

Comment: I need the name of the page that call base class, in this case, "T350112A".

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to get the *derived* class name and namespace, instead of the base page name and namespace (since that will never change). You would simply get a call to `GetType` to get this information:

```
  public override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
       Type derivedType = GetType();
       string typeName = derivedType.Name;
       string namespace = derivedType.Namespace;
  }
```

The `GetType` call will get the information for the *running* type.

Comment: In the base class I want to get dinamically: pageBaseTypeName = "T350112A"